# Azure DevOps: how to check if there is items waiting in Pool queue

Tags: queue, azure-devops

I wish to monitor private pool queue if there is waiting items in queue. If there is one waiting (which means that there is not enough agents to serve request) - I wish to add more VMs with agents. But I could not find any API endpoint, which will answer me, if there is any items in current pool queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to locate any api, which will be able to tell me how much tasks is in queue for an agent pool currently, so, I found my way around:

1. Query https://dev.azure.com/{instanceName}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents - this will show me how much agents I have and how much of them is online
2. Query https://dev.azure.com/{instanceName}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/jobrequests - this shows **all jobs** in this pool, **including** running one (theirs status will be null).

So, if amount of jobs is lower than amount of online agents - I am OK. As soon as amount of jobs is higher than online agents - I can employ SDK to add more agents in VMSS (until license permits, though)